# HTML: How can you move the position of an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML table.  Nothing too fancy.  It has the thead and the tbody.  I was wondering how I can using javascript or jQuery to move the tbody only down.

Edit:
So to give you some context about what I'm doing.  I have a table with some information(who cares what it is).  Using jQuery I fixed the header in place so that when I scroll down the header is still in place.  It is all working well, with the little problem that the header and the first row overlap.  So I need to move the top of the tbody down.  Meaning The header will stay in place and the body will be moved down a little so that I can see the first row of the table(ie. first row after the header).

I was wondering if there was a way of doing this with jQuery or javascript.

Comment: What do you mean by _"move [it] down"_? To later in the _DOM Tree_? Style it differently?

Comment: Could you give a little more context about what you want to do? This sounds like something better achieved with CSS rather than javascript.

Comment: Show us some code, describe exactly what you want. An example in a jsFiddle would be perfect

Comment: why not add TR so it comes to new row

Comment: Please show us some code, the questions is actually not clear at all. If you're wondering if you can move the tbody, then specify exactly what you need to do!

Comment: How did you fix the header in place?  Can you show us some code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use jQuery's scroll method http://api.jquery.com/scroll/

I would need more information but it sounds like you'd do something like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $("table").animate({marginTop: 50}, 250);
});
```

**EDIT:** I know this answer has been accepted as correct but it seems I misunderstood the question, as apparent by the downvotes. I thought OP was after getting the table to slide down and stay fixed just as the header does. I suggested the scroll method as that is how you'd get the table to change position states on scroll.

As others have pointed out you simply want to push the table down for the height of the header + the spacing desired, like so:

```
table {
    margin-top: 80px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was what I needed.  I am sorry to everyone else that I didn't post the code because the relevant section is about 300 lines and the code itself is a bit over 9000 lines with 9 external .js files.  So jsFiddle couldn't handle it.

Comment: Whether or not this solved the problem for you, this is not the right way to do it. With this code, you are running an animate function every time a scroll event fires, which happens tens of times every scroll swipe. In addition, you are continually animating the property to the same position, which will have no effect after the first run. You should not be using jquery for this at all, the same effect can be achieved with css.

Comment: As a demonstration, I set up this fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/NvCET/). Scroll and watch the function call count skyrocket. Then try *deleting all the javascript* and running it again. Note that there's no difference. By adding js in there, you are just spinning cycles, which is an unnecessary waste and not the correct way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've tentatively tried to reproduce your issue here. There are certainly better ways to achieve the same effect, but is this the kind of code you have? There's no need to use jquery to keep the table header fixed, so I used css:

http://jsfiddle.net/LLjdk/

Relevant CSS:

```
thead {
    position: fixed;
    background: #fff;
}

table {
    margin-top: 28px
}
```

Note that the table header is fixed (moves with scroll), and the background is set so that when the rest of the table goes behind it, it doesn't show through. Finally, there's a margin added to the top of the table to bump it down so they don't overlap.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for but from your description I understand that you're trying to make the `thead` always appear on the top of the page. Here is what I came up with.

```
thead {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: white;
}
table {
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FCZbe/)**

Hope it'll help you